# cache a part of web page using browser caching

Tags: html, caching, yii, browser-cache, html5-appcache

I'm using yii framework in my web app. 
I have huge size website Main Navigation Menu. It's a separate file named as Menu.html. 
After some parsing using php it is rendered on the browser. 
So the structure is something like:

```
{header}
{parsingMethod(menu.html)}
{middle content}
{footer}
```

So, on each hit the menu is parsed and rendered. 
Is there a way that, once menu is loaded on client; it stored in browser cache. so that after consecutive hit it dose not load from server each time??

Although, I'm using Memcached to store menu.html so that application don't need to read menu.html file from disk each time. But I want to save this Memcached hit also once the menu is loaded on client.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks
Ashu

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand HTML5 appcache, there is no way to cache a certain part of a page. If you don't want to go through parsing and rendering the menu on each request, you can still make use of Yii's [fragment caching](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/caching.fragment).

Comment: fragment caching is again server side caching. I'm already using Memcached for server side caching for the "Menu.html" file.
is there a way to cache the menu.html file through .htaccess file?

Comment: Only if the parsed menu were a file in itself and it would be loaded through an iframe. Caching of partial resources is beyond the powers of virtually every webserver I am aware of.